# Heroku custom domain name

Tags: domain-name-system, domain-name, heroku

Hi I registered a domain name on "Europe Registry", it's a .eu domain name.

I tried to edit the DNS section of my account on Europe Registry and managed to establish a 301 permanent redirect to myapp.herokuapp.com which worked fine.

However I'd like to be able to log on to my original .eu domain name, without being re-directed to Heroku if that makes sense.

The address bar, would still show www.mydomain.eu but obviously the content would be served from heroku.

How do I accomplish this? Is it by using a CNAME?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you would use a CNAME to myapp.herokuapp.com.

Additionally, you have to tell Heroku to accept the custom domain as valid, basically by running something like:

```
$ heroku domains:add www.mydomain.eu
```

to your app.

Documentation can be found here: [Heroku Custom Domains](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains)

Comment: Hey CJC thanks for your answer. At the moment I have HOST-TYPE-CONTENTS as:
www.myapp.eu CNAME myapp.herokuapp.com. However a host www.myapp.eu returns a " not found: 3(NXDOMAIN) "

Comment: pic.twitter.com/cmz0MQKy

Comment: That's a question for your DNS provider.

Comment: Thanks once again for your help CJC. The CNAME is finally working, however I can still access myapp.herokuapp.com.
Anyway to keep users from accessing it on that URL and only allow them to access wwww.myapp.com?

Comment: Not to my knowledge.  myapp.herokuapp.com is always accessible.  You can't keep people from going there, but you certainly don't need to publicize it, and I don't think anyone will really care.